# Button "show content" issues React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to create posts with components each post have:
Title, body and button "read more"

All posts was made by fetching data from training API, but i can't figure out why my buttons aren't working

that's post component:

```
export default function Post (title, body) {
    return (
      <div className="Post" data-postArr>
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <p>{body}</p>
        <button className="readMore">Read more</button>
      </div>
    )
};
```

what was the idea:
creating arrays of buttons and posts and when button clicked change className for post with the same array index (in CSS I made 2 different styles for both conditions)

```
const allButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('readMore');
const buttonArr = [...allButtons];
const allPosts = document.querySelectorAll('data-postArr');
const postsArr = [...allPosts];

for (let i = 0; i < buttonArr.length; i++) {
  buttonArr[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (postsArr[i].className === 'Post') {
      postsArr[i].className = 'PostClicked'
    } else {
      postsArr[i].className = 'Post'
    }
  })
}
```

FIXED

```
export default function Post (title, body) {

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (e.target.parentNode.className === "Post") {
      e.target.parentNode.className = "PostClicked"
    } else {
      e.target.parentNode.className = "Post"
    }
  }
  return (
      <div className="Post">
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <p>{body}</p>
        <button className="readMore" onClick={handleClick}>Read more</button>
      </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: Directly interacting with the DOM in React is very nearly *always* the wrong approach.  Honestly, your second code snippet should pretty much be abandoned.  This is a good time to go through some introductory React tutorials to see how click handlers are used in that framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of directly adding DOM event listeners, pass in a callback prop that your component can trigger...

```jsx
export default function Post({ title, body, selected, onReadMoreClick }) {
  return (
    <div className={selected ? "PostClicked" : "Post"}>
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <p>{body}</p>
      <button className="readMore" onClick={onReadMoreClick}>
        Read more
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When you render these `Post` components, you can then bind the appropriate function...

```jsx
const [selectedPost, setSelectedPost] = useState();

const selectPost = (post) => {
  setSelectedPost(post);
};

return (
  <>
    {posts.map((post) => (
      <Post
        key={post.id}
        selected={post === selectedPost}
        title={post.title}
        body={post.body}
        onReadMoreClick={() => selectPost(post)}
      />
    ))}
  </>
);
```